# Ordering posts by date

Tags: php, wordpress

I have inherited a website that uses modules for feed of posts, events etc.

The module I am trying to edit lists events, which should just display upcoming events and hide past events.

At the moment there are a few oddities, one is that it isn't ordering properly by date, there is a strange bug which means that may is showing after april. Also, it is showing events that are in the past.

Could someone help me resolve this? Here is the code:

```
<?php

extract(array(
    'events' => []
), EXTR_SKIP);

$heading = (($heading) ? $heading : 'Member Events');
?>

<div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-md-3 isotope-item">

    <div class="panel panel-default module module-member-event">

        <div class="panel-heading">

            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" href="/event-listings">See All</a>
            <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $heading; ?></h3>

        </div>

        <div class="list-group" data-compare>

            <?php $args = array('order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'date'); foreach($events as $event ): ?>

                <a href="<?php echo $event['url']; ?>" class="list-group-item">
                    <?php render_template('subtitle-with-date', array('text' => $event['title'], 'date' => $event['date'])); ?>
                </a>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are not using $args anywhere

Comment: <?php $args = array('order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'date'); foreach($events as $event ): ?>

Comment: I need a bit oof hand holding with this

Answer (score 0):

Your code using 'order' => 'ASC' and 'orderby'=> 'date' in same $args array. Which means your data is being fetched by date and showing by ASC order. That's why your facing this issue. Usr same code just removing 'order' => 'ASC' argument and your data will be showing up nicely. For further reading visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked: http://b4-business.white-staging.co.uk/  also, do you know how i might hide past events? It's the 'Member events' module at the bottom.